# Should I be worried if grease leaks from inside the new electric drill?

Tags: drill, powertools

I've just received my newly ordered drilling kit ([Skil 6513 550 watts 13 mm Impact Drill](http://www.amazon.in/Skil-6513-Variable-Hammering-Function/dp/B00I9IKEDS?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00)). I found  some sort of grease or oil around the chuck (on its surface) as soon as I opened the package and dust was around it which I cleaned it now.

[image]

Originally, I received another machine and I saw the same grease (in a different place, i.e, near the cord) so I requested for a replacement then and got this new one with a similar issue.

[image]

**What made me worrying?**

- E-commerce websites like Amazon & Flipkart are sending refurbished products these days and I am extremely worried about tools which needed to use for a
  long time.
- Earlier, I received a refurbished one and it was proved
- The original serial number on the drill machine was covered by
  another (a sticker)
- The cord has scratches on it and I'm worried whether it lasts long

Could anybody tell me in what circumstances grease leaks from inside the drill machine? Also, other tools like pliers were not fixed well in the case and I saw them shuffled. Will that damage the drill kit?

Comment: Was there grease on various locations on the drill when you received it, or have you actually found grease leaking from within?

Comment: In this package #2, grease is on the tip of the chuck ring and surrounding it. After rubbing it, some part of it turned like a hard gum and you can see it in grey color (on the tip of the ring) in the pic #1. I am not seeing it inner wall of the chuck. But in the returned package, i.e., #1, it seemed (pic #2) like leaking.

Comment: Please check this screenshot - http://www.ge.tt/9k9RCEb2. I am seeing the grease in those two places (cannot be clearly seen in the picture). I've highlighted the locations to get an idea.

Comment: For a record, the cord has scratches on it and also the chuck (http://www.ge.tt/2Lq5DEb2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Should I be worried if grease leaks from inside the new electric drill?**

No.

You should only be worried if it *continues* to leak out after being regularly used and cleaned for a week or so.

It looks like it *might* be a low-cost no-brand hand-held cabled electric-drill. So if it was bargain priced I'd be happy there is some evidence that the assembler used lubricants at all, even though sloppily.

> **I am extremely worried about tools which needed to use for a long time.**

If is this is to be used lightly once a year and *"long time"*  means 5 to 10 years you should be fine.

Otherwise it might be better to choose a more expensive tool engineered for durability rather than for low-price.

> **in what circumstances grease leaks from inside the drill machine?**

The assembler was a little too liberal in applying grease? If so, after some use this issue will go away.

Maybe its a low-cost grease rather than a higher cost, [more sticky kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum_disulfide) of grease?

> **other tools like pliers were not fixed well in the case and I saw them shuffled. Will that damage the drill kit?**

No. Tools *"needed for use for a long time"* usually end up superficially battered. Often considerably so. Normally utility is valued over preservation of pristine beauty. Your Mileage May Vary.

If it's a Festool for your Bauhaus pegboard, take it back?

Comment: Hello @redgrittybrick , it's of [Skil](http://www.amazon.in/Skil-6513-Variable-Hammering-Function/dp/B00I9IKEDS?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00) and a bit expensive.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, I saw other Skil drill machines (new) from the same brand (&model) and didn't find such grease on them.

Comment: @IamSJ. It looks like a bargain price to me. It looks like it is aimed at a beginner DIY person for occasional light use, not at professional tradesman who will use it every day, many hours a day. I've not seen excess grease on the outside of drills I've bought, except for maybe a really cheap Chinese SDS drill. I suspect you are worrying too much though about the grease.

Comment: Yes, that is for DIY purposes. I agree on worrying too much. These online marketplaces in India are sending refurbished products often (not grease related issues :) ) and that makes me overthink even on this minor issue.

Comment: In USA/CA... if you buy from Target, Menards, "sold by and ships from" Amazon etc. you can count on new, first run, non-counterfeit product in fancy tamperproof packaging.  Manfacturers sell "refurb" but that usually means a first-line product made and passed QA in China, sold to a US customer, rejected for reasons nothing to do with quality, QA'd again in the US, and resold.  Those are OK.  If you buy off eBay or random Amazon marketplace seller for an unusually low price, especially if the item ships from China, you have reason to doubt authenticity, it could have failed QA in China.

Comment: @Harper I'm unsure about "random Amazon marketplace seller" and "ships from china". Could you tell me if you mean products purchased outside Amazon by directly from an amazon seller? That's unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 3):

It's a tool, and they use grease during assembly. The jaws of the chuck should have grease on the outer surface where they meet the collar. Spots of grease elsewhere are incidental and shouldn't be cause for concern. Those aren't necessarily assembled in "white glove" conditions.

Further, once you use it, since it has moving/spinning parts, you might see excess grease weep out in places. Again, I wouldn't be concerned as long as it operates smoothly without harsh grinding or other noises.

Comment: Could you tell me if that is also common near the cord (as shown in pic #2)? One of their officials told me there are no chances for any grease to be in that location.

Comment: That looks like it came from the outside, not the inside. That's what I referred to as incidental. Like someone assembling it or boxing it up had some on their hands. Or perhaps they use a spot of lubricant to slide the cord through the strain relief.

Comment: I saw it (package #1 in pic #2) coming from inside and I think you are right on "...lubricant to slide the cord". Thanks!